# Flex Remoting - Change of Object Names during Data Serialization

Tags: java, apache-flex

While passing data (Data Serialization) from Java (server) to Flex (client) the names of the object are getting changed. Please find the details below.

## Java Pojo

```
public class MSC
{
   public String Column1;
   public String Column2;
}
```

## Java Remote Class

```
public List<MSC> getData()
{
   MSC pojoMSC = new MSC;
   pojoMSC.Column1 = "1";
   pojoMSC.Column2 = "2";

   List<MSC> listMSC = new ArrayList<MSC>;
   listMSC.add(pojoMSC);
   return listMSC;
}
```

## Flex Result Handler

```
var ReturnData:ArrayColelction = event.result as ArrayCollection;
```

When I debug and Watch for Expression ReturnData I get the following

```
ReturnData
  [0]
     column1   "1"
     column2   "2"
```

Though the process is all correct and the values too are all correct, the names of the objects of 0 index of ReturnData is changed from Column1 to column1 and Column2 to column2.

I think this done by Flex AMF Data Serilization. How could it be prevented so that I can get Coulmn1 as Column1 etc. If not what is the concept behind it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because BlazeDS uses Java Bean naming convention.

First of all, in Java you don't name class's members (fields, methods) starting with a capital letter.

Second, it is a good practice to follow encapsulation principles and make your fields private and use getters/setters to mutate them.

In you case this would be like this:

```
public class MSC
{
   private String column1;
   private String column2;

   public String getColumn1(){
      return column1;
   }

   public void setColumn1(String value) {
      column1 = value;
   }  

   public String getColumn2(){
      return column2;
   }

   public void setColumn2(String value) {
      column2 = value;
   } 
}
```

But in general: DON'T start variables with a capital letter.

Comment: First question: how important for you to have field names starting from the capital letter? Because there is a Flex/ActionScript coding convention as well (http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Coding%20Conventions/) and it does not allow to name variables and fields starting from the capital letter.

Comment: Well it's not that important but have to change them according to the CodingConvention. Thanks for the prompt reply, will refer the documentation.